# Using a keyboard shortcut to paste text

Tags: shortcut-keys

There are lots of websites which only allow signing in with email address and password and I am tired of typing a long email address. I don't want my browser to remember my email. Can I assign a keyboard shortcut to print this email address so that every time I press the key I get my email address on current text field?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have very little knowledge about Ubuntu. I'm not talking about snippets. Just a defined text to paste when the key is pressed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To paste a *single string* into a textfield

1. install both `xdotool` and `xclip`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool xclip
   ```
2. Add the following command to a shortcut key:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 0.5 && printf 'youremail@server.com' | xclip -selection clipboard && xdotool key Control_L+v"
   ```

   Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command above to a key combination of your choice.

Now when enter the cursor in a textfield and choose your shortcut, it will type your email address.

Comment: Out of interest, why is the `sleep 0.5` necessary? I noticed that it does not work without this.

Comment: @Exeleration-G If I remember well (it is a while ago) it is to make sure the shortcut keypress does not interfere with the simulated keypress by `xdotool`.

Comment: `xdotool type --clearmodifiers 'youremail@server.com'`

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm I tried your method, but got disable for the shortcut no matter which key combinations I tried.

Comment: `sleep` duration can be customised. Lower will leave you less time to release your key combination but the text will come sooner.

Comment: You can try to replace `xclip -selection clipboard` with `xsel -b`. Requires to install the `xsel` package.

Comment: Will erase the *Ctrl+V* clipboard, here replacing its content by `youremail@server.com`

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.
Similar to [Jacob’s solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/754906/834652). Here, we will paste the text `hello ♥` using the middle mouse click clipboard.

We won’t paste the text at the "| cursor" as using *Ctrl+V* but directly under the mouse cursor like when using the middle mouse click. You may replace `xsel` with `xclip`.

1. Install `xdotool` and `xsel`:

```bash
sudo apt install xdotool xsel
```

2. Add the following command to a shortcut key:

```bash
/bin/bash -c 'echo -n "hello ♥" | xsel && xdotool click 2'
```

**Note:** We use the clipboard of the middle mouse, so expect it to be erased along with the current selection when using your custom shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

As none of suggestions that I found were able to achieve what I wanted, I had to do my own research into the subject. Posting my one-liner below in case if someone ever wants to achieve something similar. Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.1.

### What I needed?

One-liner that would paste my signature to websites (sounds stupid, I know, but to my surprise there's still no decent way to achieve that with Google Chrome) when I press the set hotkey.

### What was wrong with the one-liner from @zatiranyk?

While technically it does achieve what I want, for reason I still don't understand it's not pasting text when clicking the set hotkey.

### Preprequisites

**xdotool** and **xsel** are still going to be required. You can install them like this:

```
sudo apt install xdotool xsel
```

### My version of the one-liner

```
bash -c 'echo -e "SIGNATURE" | xsel -b && seq 2 | xargs -I -- xdotool key ctrl+shift+v'
```

If you bind it to, say, super+v, every time you press super+v it would paste the set text ("SIGNATURE").

Here's a short breakdown of its parts:

1. **echo -e "SIGNATURE"** -- I'm using -e with echo here because my signature has a few \n in it
2. **xsel -b** -- this basically tells the shell to copy the input (**echo -e "SIGNATURE"**) to the clipboard
3. **seq 2** -- this exists in order to run the thing that's following it (**xargs -I -- xdotool key ctrl+shift+v**) twice* (see **Observations**)
4. **xdotool key ctrl+shift+v** -- **xdotool** simulates keyboard input, and in this case it's **ctrl+shift+v**, which's the default hotkey for pasting content from the clipboard

In other words, what this one liner does is it:

1. Copies signature to the clipboard
2. Forces pressing **ctrl+shift+v** 2 times to paste the clipboard content

**Observations**

- Why the part **xdotool key ctrl+shift+v** is executed twice? Similar to the one-liner of @zatiranyk, pressing **ctrl+shift+v** one time does not do the trick for some reason
- For whatever reason similar one-liner with the primary selection instead of the clipboard works 3-4 times out of 10:

  ```
    bash -c 'echo -e "SIGNATURE" | xsel && seq 2 | xargs -I -- xdotool click 2'
  ```
- A bit more unga bunga version of the one-liner will work like a charm too:

  ```
    bash -c 'echo -e "SIGNATURE" | xsel -b && xdotool key ctrl+shift+v && xdotool key ctrl+shift+v'
  ```

Comment: Please, improve the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `xdotool key Control_L+v` is:

```
$ echo "TEST String" | xclip -in -selection clipboard
$ xdotool type --delay 0 -- "$(xclip -out -selection clipboard)"
```